# On-site photography workshop in Nepal or India

Tags: india, photography, study, trekking, nepal

I am an amateur photographer but do not have the patience to take classes to get better. I've heard of good workshops being taught while trekking in the Andes or the Himalaya but I cannot find anything that I like on the net. Any experience would be useful and links or addresses to on site workshops in Nepal or India are welcome.

Comment: By "workshops" you mean a kind of study right? I'm adding a relevant tag under that assumption ...

Comment: Yes, by workshop, I mean traveling with someone who is teaching you some skills. In my case, I love mountains and trekking and would like to it with a small group and a photographer tour leader who will share his passion.
Thanks for adding a tag
Katie

Comment: Andes, Nepal, and India are VERY big regions. Could you please edit your question to give it a bit more geographic focus or details to narrow it down?

Answer (score 3):

[Darter Photography](http://www.darter.in/) conducts a photography tour in Lahaul-Spiti region. There is one tour planned in [July 13 - 20, 2013](http://www.darter.in/photography-tours/travel/lahaul-spiti-photography-tour/)

PS: I'm not affiliated to this group. One of the co-founders of Darters is a friend.

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out. Concerning the region, it doesn't really matter it will depend of the program and the price of course...

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting workshop in Nepal next October with a small group (5/6 people) for amateurs photographers. Check this: http://www.photography-trekking.asia/
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

http://photographyonthemove.com conducts pretty good photography workshops in small groups.

Eg: http://photographyonthemove.com/photography-workshop-spiti-valley-himachal-tourism-lahaul-treks/
This was a 11 day tour in the Tibet region.